# Tensorflow: get predicted values

Tags: tensorflow

I have downloaded an example code of MLP and trying to understand how it works. I came accross this line where it calculates the accuracy of test datasets.

```
accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: data_test, y: labels_test, dropout_keep_prob:1.})
```

Now, I want to get the predicted labels as well. How can I get the predicted labels?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the prediction tensor. If you have the code it's the one you compare to `y` to compute the accuracy. Say it's called `prediction`, then you can write:

```
accuracy, prediction = sess.run([accuracy, prediction], feed_dict={X: data_set, y:labels_test, ...})
```